# How to launch a Jar file using Spark on hadoop

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform

I'm doing a project on Google Cloud Platform on which I installed hadoop. I wrote a program in scala and created an executable JAR using the assembly instruction of sbt
Now I have to upload and run it on my platform. I tried to use the command `spark-submit --class "Hi" provaciao.jar`
but I get an error even if it works in local on the spark standalone.
I use the version 1.1.0 of spark and 2.4 of hadoop

This is my error log

> marooned91_gmail_com@hadoop-m-on8g:/home/hadoop/spark-install/bin$
>   spark-submit --class "Hi" provaciao.jar
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hi
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>               at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
>               at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:318)
>               at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
>               at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Comment: check your jar! jar -tf provacaio.jar. Your class might be missing

Comment: no because it works in local

Comment: even if it's local. I think that what you might be doing is packing your app  with sbt or maven. So your app jar doesn't contain the jar libraries.

Comment: And what about permissions in the hadoop folder? i don't know if I can actually access the file

Comment: Did you try what I have told you?

Comment: i made the jar using the instruction assembly of sbt

Comment: and did you look what's inside your jar???

Comment: Yes, the main class is Hi and the only .class file is Hi.class

Answer (score 1):

try to Add full package path to Hi class. If you don't specified package for class, do it.

Like

spark-submit --class "com.mycompany.something.Hi" provaciao.jar

Also unzip your jar file and check that Hi class exists in it